How do I add C to the end of a float integer?
I am trying to make a program that lets the user enter a number and then rounds it to one decimal place. I am just struggling to get 'C' at the end as requested. I can only seem to manage to get it with a space before 'C'. My code is this:
air_temperature = float(input())
print('{:.1f}'.format(air_temperature))

So far, I have managed 36.4 C  only  not  36.4C

What exactly have you done? Show us your code not images.

Have you tried writing C somewhere in your code? For example after {:.1f} which is the number with one decimal digit.

Thank you for the response and letting me know a better way to ask questions moving forward.

You're new here, therefore one advise: Don't put images of source code into your question. Same goes for error messages, so that they can be conveniently searched for. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. That said, online "teachers" (most notoriously leetcode) often have the problem that they tell you something is wrong, but not what. This then leads to questions asking people to fix code, without even being able to clearly state the problem. I mention this, because your snapshots seem to be from some automated online tutoring system.

To say a number and some text after it in Python, you can just type
print(str(number) + "some text")

So to do what you are asking, you can just do
air_temp = float(input())       #Getting the temperature
air_round = round(air_temp, 1)  #Rounding it to one decimal place
print(str(air_round) + "C")     #Printing the temperature rounded

You could also do this with f-strings like so:
air_temp = float(input())       #Getting the temperature
air_round = round(air_temp, 1)  #Rounding it to one decimal place
print(f"{air_round}C")          #Printing the temperature rounded

You can do this with one less line of code like this:
air_temp = float(input())       #Getting the temperature
print(f"{air_round:.1f}C")      #Printing the temperature rounded

Or using .format like this:
air_temp = float(input())       #Getting the temperature
print("{:.1f}C".format(air_temp)#Printing the temperature rounded


This is what you are looking for. With f-strings, this is easier to achieve.
air_temperature = float(input())
print(f'{air_temperature:.1f}C')

